# Month slicer and filter not working properly on rolling data Power BI

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

i All.

I have created below measure to reflects always 3 month figures when month slicer is used.

```
3R =
CALCULATE(COUNT('Order'[Order/ not ordered]),DATESINPERIOD('Date'[Date],LASTDATE('Date'[Date]),-3,MONTH)))
```

However, when I try to add salesman figures as filter with below formula, and click to month slicer it is directly show just choosen month figures not 3 months.

```
3R John =
CALCULATE(COUNT('Order'[Order/ notordered])
,DATESINPERIOD('Date'[Date],LASTDATE('Date'[Date]),-3,MONTH),FILTER('Order','Order'[Salesman]="John")))
```

on below link I have shared a sample for this. there are 2 different table and 1 matrix.
Matrix is named working and 1 of the table is named as "not working properly". not selecting any value on slicer. all data gives same data. however when clicked month slicer not named main table is changing and this is correct. also matrix is correct but table that I am trying to achive is not working.

What i am trying to achive is, 3 month roling data based on customer and salesman. when click for example 1 on month slicer table should give January 2020, December 2019 and November 2019 figures.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LoqSiKhHMFn_OioI2RnXOzjcIL9dPRjS/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is the solution. worked for me.

```
3R John =CALCULATE(COUNT('Order'[Order/notordered]),DATESINPERIOD('Date'[Date],LASTDATE('Date'[Date]),-3,MONTH),'Order'[Salesman]="John"))
```

just remove filter('order', section and it is ok now.